# How to force SSL on a specific file example.org/index.html?

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl

I have a php based website....i trying to use ssl...the ssl is working fine in site, the problem is it not redirect with https....it only show http
and i try to edit in .htaccess file, but its not working....
also my site open with this format example.org/**index.html** with **/index.html**

i trying to use this, but not working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

**.htaccess code:**

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /
#AuthUserFile /home/products/html/path/.htpasswd
#AuthGroupFile /dev/null
#AuthName "Private Area"
#AuthType Basic
#<Limit GET POST>
#require valid-user
#</Limit>

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, Public"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

Options -Indexes

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ $1/?%{QUERY_STRING}

-------urls---------

RewriteRule ^index/$ path/index.php
RewriteRule ^index/([^\/]+)/$ path/index.php?list=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to redirect.

I use this function to check if the request is HTTPS or not:

```
function isHttps() {
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] === 443;
}
```

And now check if the request is not HTTPS, and redirect:

```
if (!isHttps()) {
    header("location: https://www.example/index.php");
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use PHP for redirections, this can be achieved by any webserver configuration, which means it will be faster, simpler, and more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Force redirect to secure page:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '443') { 
    header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
    exit(); 
}
```